# Угадывание введенного числа

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Помогите решить задачку: пользователю предлагают ввести число от 1 до 100 через (prompt), затем второму пользователю педлагают угадать заданое число (prompt), после чего он либо угадывает либо его просят ввести снова, при этом говоря больше или меньше число. После вывести за сколько попыток угадал.  P.S.Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: > Только не через функцию.

Фантастика.

Comment: @FantomRed, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @FantomRed, тут до Вас кто-то уже задавал такой же вопрос. Только (насколько помню) сформулирован хуже.

Для Вашей формулировки посоветую угадывать двоичным поиском.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Псевдокод:

```
write("Введите число: ")  
read(x);  
i = 0  
tmp = x-1  
while (tmp !== x) do  
   write("Угадай число, ну же: ")  
   read(tmp)    
   if (tmp !==x) write("Неправильно, число ", (x < tmp) ? "больше" : "меньше", " чем нужно")  
   i++  
end  
write("Угадали за ", i, " попыток")
```

На JS сами напишите

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Вот только зачем минусов понаставили непонятно,нет я конечно понимаю что тут все очень умные люди куда мне до вас.Постараюсь больше лишний раз к вам не обращаться и всем своим знакомым тоже посоветую.

Comment: @FantomRed просто тут не принято делать __всю__ работу за человека.